# Does the libharu-RELEASE_2_3_0 support Russian text display?

Tags: libharu

I Checked the libharu-RELEASE_2_3_0,there are hpdf_encoder_cns.c,hpdf_encoder_cnt.c,hpdf_encoder_jp.c,hpdf_encoder_utf.c
which code support Russian text ?

Answer (score 0):

The UTF-8 `hpdf_encoder_utf.c` should support Cyrillic letters.

Comment: thanks,I'll have a try. In fact ,I am using  an old libharu and there is a sample called encoding_list.c.It use different encoding style to show characters.I want to show Russian sentences in PDF .so I have to set the codes file as KOI8-R ,even this,the result is not nice, It can show Russian text,but for blanks,it shows '?'

Comment: Do you used the latest libharu?

Comment: yes ,I use it and generate the pdf with Russian. <pre>HPDF_UseUTFEncodings(pdf);
 HPDF_SetCurrentEncoder(pdf,"UTF-8");

 detail_font_name = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile (pdf, "ttfont/arial.ttf", HPDF_TRUE);

    title_font = HPDF_GetFont (pdf, "Helvetica", NULL);

 detail_font = HPDF_GetFont (pdf, detail_font_name, "UTF-8");<code>

Comment: yes,I use this code to generate pdf with Russian.but I have to embed arial.ttf into pdf . And the pdf size is sure large.Is there any solution to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    HPDF_UseUTFEncodings(pdf);
HPDF_SetCurrentEncoder(pdf,"UTF-8");

detail_font_name = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile (pdf, "ttfont/arial.ttf", HPDF_TRUE);

title_font = HPDF_GetFont (pdf, "Helvetica", NULL);

detail_font = HPDF_GetFont (pdf, detail_font_name, "UTF-8");
```

yes,I use this code to generate pdf with Russian.but I have to embed arial.ttf into pdf .
And the pdf size is sure large.Is there any solution to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just do **NOT** want to embed used font into your generated PDF document, just use the following:

```c
detail_font_name = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile (pdf, "ttfont/arial.ttf", HPDF_FALSE);
```

The result PDF will not have a font embedded, not even a subset.
But this requires the PDF viewer to pick the right glyph.